# .NET6- Login User using JWT token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have two projects one client-side in MVC and the second a Web API project, both are in .Net 6.

**Web API side**
I want to Authenticate users coming to the client side. I know that to add authentication to Web API most recommended way is a JWT token. So I added the below code to my Web API program.cs class to use JWT authentication.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
});
```

Next, I added a login method as below in the Web API that simply generates the JWT token and returns the token. Not adding GenerateToken() code to keep things simple

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("login")]
public JsonResult Login()
{
    var token = TokenHelper.GenerateToken();

    return new JsonResult(new { token = token });
}
```

**Client-side**
On the client-side, I have configured cookie authentication which checks if the user is not authenticated, it will redirect the user to the login page on the client-side

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/Forbidden/";
        options.LoginPath = "/home/login/";
    });
```

On the login page, I ask the user to enter their username and password and then call the login endpoint in the Web API project that issues a token. I successfully get the token.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7157/");

      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("WeatherForecast/login");

      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
         var token= await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TokenModel>();
      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
      }
}
```

Now, this is the point where I am struggling. I want to sign in user using this token on the client-side something like generate a cookie using token or use HttpContext.SignInAsync to sign in the user. I have the token but not sure what is the best practice to log in the user or how to use that token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want  cookie authentication(as you setted in your MVC project),you  could use ReadToken() method to read the claims inside the token, and generate the ClaimsIdentity which is required in
HttpContext.SignInAsync()method

```
                var jsonToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
                var username = jsonToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
                 .............
                 //add other logic
                if (username==user.Name)
                {
                    var claims = new Claim[]
                    {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
                     };
                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
                }
```

if you want JWT Authentication in your MVC project,you could set as below :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     ......
                 };
                 options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                 {

                     OnMessageReceived = context =>
                     {
                         var accessToken = context.Request.Cookies["token"];
                         
                         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
                         {
                             context.Token = accessToken;
                         }

                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                     }
                 };
```

add the token in your login controller:

```
Response.Cookies.Append("token", token);
```

Comment: So if i use that token returned from Web API to sign in user and put an [Authorize] attribute on client side method and try to access that method, will the .NET framework check whether the user is signed In or not?

Comment: Yes,you could read the document related:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authenticate