# Customize asp .net authentication using JWT token

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I want to customize my ASP .NET application's authentication and authorization (roles included) using my own logic. I'm using a JWT token. I do not want ASP .NET to check my token for me, I want to check the token myself and then override the authentication and Authorization with roles.

The steps I want:

1. I want to implement Authentication and Authorization
2. Then I want to retrieve the token.
3. I want to implement my own logic wether the token is valid or not
4. I want to tell ASP .Net whether the authentication has suceeded or not based on my logic.

**What I have tried (Which is not completely overiding ASP .Net's Authentication method ):**

```
builder.AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                // JWT Validation
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuers = new[] { "http://localhost:8080/realms/GT" },
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = BuildRSAKey(publicKeyJWT),
                    ValidateLifetime = true
                };

                o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = async c =>
                    {
                        if (c.Token == null)
                        {
                            c.NoResult();

                            c.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                            c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                            await c.Response.WriteAsync("No token was provided");

                            return;
                        }

                        // custom logic to check token

                        // if true then Success
                        // else fail

                        BuildClaims(c.Principal);  // roles claims included
                        return;
                    }
                };
            });
```

In the code I am calling the OnMessageReceived event, but the problem is that **c.Token** is null. Thus, I cannot retrieve the token using this method.

Is there a way to retreive the token using this method or is there another way to customize ASP .Net's authentication process with my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to retreive the token using this method

You could check MessageReceivedContext class and found the description :

> This will give the application an opportunity to retrieve a token from
> an alternative location.

[image]

It means you could try as below to spcific how to receive the token yourself

From cookie:

```
x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["JWTToken"];
            .......                
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
```

From Request header:

```
context.Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

I once tried read token from cookie in a mvc project:
[.NET6- Login User using JWT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708187/net6-login-user-using-jwt-token/72711403#72711403)