# How to use Authentication Filters in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) guide to setup authentication filters in an API I created. It was all pretty easy and went well except now when testing, I get this exception

> No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

whenever I try to hit an endpoint.

I've looked at [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) as well, where it does set the `authenticationScheme` like so

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => builder.Configuration.Bind("JwtSettings", options))
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        options => builder.Configuration.Bind("CookieSettings", options));
```

but I don't want any of these. Is there a way to just use authentication filter's via attribute syntax?

Here is how I have it setup.

Basic filter:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class BasicFilter : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{        
    async public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        BaseRequest? request = await AuthenticationHelper.RequestIsValid<BaseRequest>(context);
        if (request == null)
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult(context.Request);
            return;
        }

        GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("User"), null);
        context.Principal = principal;
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var challenge = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("None");
        context.Result = new ChallengeUnauthorizedResult(challenge, context.Result);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

And then just throw a `[BasicFilter]` and `[Authorize]` attribute on an endpoint like so:

```
    [Authorize]
    [BasicFilter]
    [HttpPost]
    async public Task<ActionResult> CreateAccount()
    {
    }
```

Comment: To be honest it is quite unclear what you actually want to achieve. From the code you have posted you want to just set user without any authentication which basically is the same like letting anonymous user to access the endpoint. Am I missing something?

Comment: @dropoutcoder `AuthenticationHelper.RequestIsValid` validates that the request has the required post data. If that succeeds, then yes, that is all that is needed for `Basic` authentication. There are others that are more complex

Comment: _"but I don't want any of these."_ - Why not?

Comment: @Dai they are unneeded in my project. Adding them would just be redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: So you want to use authentication and authorization without using cookies or JWT bearer tokens...? Then _how_ is your system supposed to work?

Comment: If you just wanna validate request - just use middleware - your intent is not suitable for autorization or authentication.

Comment: @J.Memisevic: If you just need to validate POST request body. You might want to use model validation for it. Check out [Part 9, add validation to an ASP.NET Core MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: @J.Memisevic middleware is a bit more of a pain to setup. I already have the Authorization Filters setup, I'd like to use them if possible. Also, if I were to use middleware, then I would be using Authentication or Authorization Middleware, no? "your intent is not suitable for autorization or authentication" doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: @J.Memisevic thanks for the suggestion, but I'd probably use middleware before model validation, if I can't use just Authorization Filters

Answer (score 0):

This [guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) you mentioned is for asp.net app not asp.net core app

In asp.net core,we could create authorize filter attribute as below:

```
    public  class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
     {
         public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
         {
             if (context != null)
             {
                  var authheader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
                 // check if the header is started with Basic and validate it yourself
                
             }
         }
     }
```

If you just want Basic Authentication,just read value from request headers and validate it yourself,like this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76528448/how-to-develop-a-custom-authorizeattribute-that-accepts-a-token-passed-as-url-pa/76529429#76529429)

Answer (score 0):

```
•   Create a Custom Authentication Filter
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class CustomAuthenticationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // Your authentication logic goes here
        // For example, you can check if the user is authenticated
        if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Handle unauthorized access
            context.Result = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        // If authenticated, you can proceed with the request
    }
}

•   Register the Filter

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(config =>
    {
        config.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomAuthenticationFilter));
    });
}


•   Apply the Filter

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomAuthenticationFilter))]
    public IActionResult MyAction()
    {
        // Your action logic here
    }
}
```